# Can Resharper be turned off for a while?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm pairing with someone who is against using resharper (don't ask me why) so I'd like it to hide without uninstalling - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For R# 5.0: Tools->Options->ReSharper->Suspend

older versions can be disabled from Add-In Manager menu

Comment: Aha, looked to much in the (massively) Resharper settings, instead of the right place, thanks mate!